# performance issue from 5 queries in one page

Tags: php, mysql, performance, filter

As i am a junior PHP Developer growing day by day stuck in a performance problem described here:
I am making a search engine in PHP ,my database has one table with 41 column and million's of rows obviously it is a very large dataset. In `index.php`  i have a form for searching data.When user enters search keyword and hit submit the action is on `search.php` with results.The query is like this.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE product_description LIKE '%mobile%' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10
```

This is the first query.After result shows i have to run 4 other query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(weight_u) as weight from TABLE WHERE product_description LIKE '%mobile%'
SELECT DISTINCT(country_unit) as country_unit from TABLE WHERE product_description LIKE '%mobile%'
SELECT DISTINCT(country) as country from TABLE WHERE product_description LIKE '%mobile%'
SELECT DISTINCT(hs_code) as hscode from TABLE WHERE product_description LIKE '%mobile%'
```

These queries are for FILTERS ,the problem is this when i submit search button ,all queries are running simultaneously at the cost of Performance issue,its very slow.
Is there any other method to fetch `weight,country,country_unit,hs_code` speeder or how can achieve it.

The same functionality is implemented here,Where the filter bar comes after table is filled with data,How i can achieve it .Please help

[Full Functionality implemented here.](http://www.datawale.com/HS-Code-84-Import-Data-India/fr-26-10-2016/to-26-11-2016)

I have tried to explain my full problem ,if there is any mistake please let me know i will improve the question,i am also new to stackoverflow.

Comment: The leading '%' means it has to look at _every_ row.  5 times!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly - are you sure this code is working as you expect it? The first query retrieves 10 records matching your search term. Those records might have duplicate `weight_u`, `country_unit`, `country` or `hs_code` values, so when you then execute the next 4 queries for your filter, it's entirely possible that you will get values back which are *not* in the first query, so the filter might not make sense.

if that's true, I would create the filter values in your client code (PHP)- finding the unique values in 10 records is going to be quick and easy, and reduces the number of database round trips.

Finally, the biggest improvement you can make is to use MySQL's [fulltext searching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) features. The reason your app is slow is because your search terms cannot use an index - you're wild-carding the start as well as the end. It's like searching the phonebook for people whose name contains "ishra" - you have to look at every record to check for a match. Fulltext search indexes are designed for this - they also help with fuzzy matching.

Comment: yes sir,i am implementing the full text index in my project. and i am confused how i can achieve the filter implemented in the given link in the last. Don't check my queries these are just for understanding.Give me some tips how can i achieve the feature in below link  ?,Also i have edited the question

Comment: Ok - so is it the case you want to retrieve a bunch of records matching a search term, and have filtering options showing the names and number of matching records?

Comment: yes.. Please visit the link i have provided i wants to same functionality on this link [link](http://www.datawale.com/HS-Code-84-Import-Data-India/fr-26-10-2016/to-26-11-2016)

Comment: https://www.codexworld.com/ajax-pagination-with-search-filter-php/ - does this answer your question?

Comment: @NevilleKuyt -`DISTINCT` is not a function; it applies to the entire `SELECT` list.  I don't think you can easily get there from what you wrote.

Comment: @NevilleKuyt - `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT weight_u), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT country_unit), ...` might be close.

Comment: Yes DISTICT can be used only once in a mysql query ?..am i right ?

Answer (score -1):

I'll give you some tips that will show useful in many situations when querying a large dataset, or mostly any dataset.

- If you can list the fields you want instead of querying for '*' is a better practice. The weight of this increases as you have more columns and more rows.
- Always try to use the PK's to look for the data. The more specific the filter, the less it will cost.
- An index in this kind of situation would come pretty handy, as it will make the search more agile.
- LIKE queries are generally pretty slow and resource heavy, and more in your situation. So again, the more specific you are, the better it will get.
- Also add, that if you just want to retrieve data from this tables again and again, maybe a VIEW would fit nicely.

Those are just some tips that came to my mind to ease your problem.
Hope it helps.

Comment: yeah i it is right but i am searching for a best solution to achieve my problem i think this is not the best method to retrieve  filter elements.